# "I will become rich even if it kills you" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

tuae divitiae mea usque ad mortem?

I'm looking for something pithy suitable for heraldry, but I fear Google Translate introduces ambiguity - I'm not looking to die, myself; but if it makes me rich, I'm indifferent to your death!

Comment: Your suggestion means something like "your wealth mine until death", which doesn't quite sound like what you want to express.

Comment: "I fear Google Translate introduces ambiguity" -- not really, Google Translate produced gibberish, as usual.

Comment: Yep, Google Translate doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

How about **dives fiam etsi pereas**?

Comment: Is that conditional on your death? I want indifference, but know zero Latin

Comment: _etsi_ means "even if, although", so it's not conditional on your death.